# IF Statement in a calculated field (SSAS Tabular)

Tags: ssas, calculated-columns

I'm in the process of creating a tabular model cube in SSAS and I've become a bit stuck on some of my measures for the calculated columns

I have already converted this case statement to an IF in SSAS

```
case when PROPERTY_CHARGE.PCH_CURRENT_IND='Y' then PROPERTY_CHARGE.PCH_AMT  else 0 end
```

is now

```
=If ([PCH_CURRENT_IND]="Y", [PCH_AMT],0)
```

I'm now struggling to convert this one:

```
  sum(case when PROPERTY_CHARGE.PCH_CURRENT_IND='N' and PROPERTY_CHARGE.PCH_END_DATE is null then PROPERTY_CHARGE.PCH_AMT else 0 end
```

I've tried various arrangements but no matter what i'm getting errors either related to is null or AND not being available in this context or other errors advising I have too many arguments.

Can anyone assist please?

Answer (score 0):

IN tabular is very different the logic, you can create a measure like this :

```
MeasureName:=CALCULATE(sum([PCH_AMT]),FILTER(PROPERTY_CHARGE,[PCH_CURRENT_IND]="N"&&[PCH_END_DATE]=BLANK()))
```

ANd give you the same result of case

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually managed to replicate it with

    =IF([PCH_CURRENT_IND]="N" , IF(LEN([PCH_END_DATE])=0,    [PCH_AMT] , 0))

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=If ([PCH_CURRENT_IND]="Y", [PCH_AMT],BLANK())
```

and then :

MeasureName:

```
=CALCULATE(sum([PCH_AMT]),FILTER(PROPERTY_CHARGE,[PCH_CURRENT_IND]="N"&&[PCH_END_DATE]=BLANK()))
```

that is the same as the case

Answer (score 0):

This solution will be a little more performant than the previous posts and a little easier to read, use this for a Measure:

```
Strruggling To Convert measure:=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'PROPERTY_CHARGE'[PCH_AMT] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'PROPERTY_CHARGE'[PCH_CURRENT_IND], 'PROPERTY_CHARGE'[PCH_END_DATE] ),
        AND (
            'PROPERTY_CHARGE'[PCH_CURRENT_IND] = "N",
            ISBLANK ( 'PROPERTY_CHARGE'[PCH_END_DATE] )
        )
    )
)

Struggling To Convert Calculate column :=
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    AND (
        'PROPERTY_CHARGE'[PCH_CURRENT_IND] = "N",
        ISBLANK ( 'PROPERTY_CHARGE'[PCH_END_DATE] )
    ), SUM ( 'PROPERTY_CHARGE'[PCH_AMT] )
)
```